# Reading from a WCF stream as objects are deserialized?

Tags: wcf, datatable, streaming, paging

I currently have a WCF service which has streaming enabled which has greatly decreased the memory usage of the client application, but I want to be able to read the objects in the stream as they are deserialized on the client and populate a DataTable instead of waiting for all the objects to be received as it still takes a long time to get all the data.

I had a read through [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx) which seems to be relevant to my goal, but it seems rather out of date. I was wondering if there is a more modern way of achieving this using WCF 4.0.

**Update:**

So I implemented the operation in my service using the method described in the article linked above, but I came across this exception at runtime:

> The operation 'GetMyDtos' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

My operation had the following signature:

```
Message GetMyDtos( bool param1, int? param2, bool param3 );
```

So I changed it to this:

```
Message GetMyDtos( GetMyDtosParameters getMyDtosParameters );
```

and GetMyDtosParameters looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetMyDtosParameters
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public bool Param1 { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader]
    public int? Param2 { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader]
    public bool Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

Everything's working fine on the service end now, but I have an issue when adding or updating a service reference to the client. The method `GetMyDtos` is generated in the client without any method parameters (and no overloads) so I cannot pass any parameters to the service operation.

**Update 2:**

I'm able to get back results from the service even without passing any parameters in. I'm guessing default values are being used since they're primitives and/or Nullables. However, I'd still like to be able to make calls to the service with different values for the parameters, but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind that article is still valid. Why do you say it's out of date? Streaming a WCF message involves mostly dealing with a WCF message itself, and the technique described there should work. Are you having any problems with it?

Comment: I haven't tried the method in that article yet, because I wanted to avoid changing the service so I suppose the real question can I do something on the client? The reason I said it's out of date is because it's from 2008 and there are a load of new features in WCF 4.0 so I thought there may be something that makes doing this easier.